# In the 18.04/bionic docker container, how do I restore manpages?

Tags: 18.04, docker, manpage, container

When building a container based on the official 18.04/bionic docker image, 
It appears to be impossible to install manages. even if I explicitly install them, they do not appear to be on the file system.

My container ends up being an interactive environment, so i DO want manages.

How do I re-enable manage support inside a bionic container?

I need to do this in a non-interactive fashion.

Comment: Add your Dockerfile to the question, please.

Comment: See this question and reverse the configurations https://askubuntu.com/questions/628407/removing-man-pages-on-ubuntu-docker-installation

Comment: Thank you @Panther, the above solved my issue
specifically:

    `if [ -f /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes ];  
      then  
        rm /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/excludes;  
        bash -c " apt install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep ii | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | tr '\n' ' ')";  
    fi`

Comment: Post that as an answer